# Switching into my app causes pasteboard to clear. iPad Paste button won't appear sometimes

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm having a really strange issue with the Pasteboard, and I'm looking for suggestions:

When switching into my app to paste some text, the text in the pasteboard sometimes gets cleared, so when I try to paste there is nothing in the pasteboard anymore.  Switching and pasting in other apps are fine, so something is unique about my app.

heres a video of the problem (simulator) and the weird work around i've found. 
http://screencast.com/t/ID57TikvFOD

Example: if i am in mail, copy some text, and then double tap home and switch to my running app, the paste option almost never appears.  When i go to my input box and press-and-hold, the Paste button never appears. 
Oddly, this behavior is not consistent as it **sometimes** works.  I'd guess about 20% of the time it works and 80% of the time the pasteboard is cleared.  I thought it might be a memory warning clearing the pasteboard, so I watched my iPad with "activity monitor" in instruments and I dont see any memory warnings.

This is driving me nuts.  I can repro the same inconsistency in my iOS 5 ipad, as well as 4.2 and 5.0 simulators.  My customer is running 4.2 and the work-around i've found (double switching) doesn't work for him.

In my code, the only time i ever reference the pasteboard i'm just putting things in it.  i never clear it.

```
- (IBAction)copyToClipboard:(id)sender {
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.string = currentCard.concept.chineseWord;
[self._delegate dismissPopover];
```

}

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Are you using Flurry Analitcs?

Comment: I am yes, but didnt notice anything for exceptions, where do you think I should look?

Comment: Check if there is a new version of the Flurry framework available. There was a version of the framework which would brake the pasteboard for app that used it.

Comment: You sir are a genius. :)  In the simulator, if i disable flurry the pasteboard works like normal.  Crazy.   thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AndreasZ's tip solved the problem for me.  Flurry was buggy and was causing the pasteboard issue.